# React Native Alert without button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to display a successful login modal with react native alert,but how can i get a alert screen without ok button

**Something just like this**

[image]

**Not this**

[image]

Thank you a lot

Comment: can you provide your code? it would help a lot

Comment: You might want to use toast message for successful login. Please check this repo if it helps https://github.com/calintamas/react-native-toast-message

Comment: sorry for this late, here is my repo https://github.com/khanh21011999/Trainning-react-native it locate in src/redux/saga/loginSaga.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the third param in *alert* method inside Alert class to configure the buttons, if you dont want any, just set an empty array

For example:

```
const alertWithoutButtons = () => {
    const title = 'Login Status';
    const message = 'Successful, letting you in...';
    const emptyArrayButtons = [];
    const alertOptions = {
      cancelable: true,
    };

    Alert.alert(title, message, emptyArrayButtons, alertOptions);
};
```

An expo snack showing: https://snack.expo.io/MHcsnGMs0

For more API details, check the documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert#methods

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe i'll use third party alert, but this is solution!